# Youcompleteme plugin for vim fails to provide completion for error codes from errno.h

Tags: python, c++, vim, youcompleteme

I've never used vim at work, only starting to familiarize myself with it and so far like it very much.

For **YouCompleteMe** plugin to work for my test project I took .ycm_extra_conf.py file from [here](https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/blob/master/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py) and added '-I/usr/include' and 'path/to/my/project/' to flags. It works very well, it can complete even c++11's `auto` types!

But I couldn't make it complete error codes like `EINTR`, `EAGAIN`, etc., that are supposed to be visible after `#include <errno.h>`

If I call `:YcmComplete GoToDeclaration` with my cursor being on `EINTR`, it's declaration is correctly found however...

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

By further googling I found out that macro completion can be obtained with (Ctrl-Space).